# The application is not open anymore

Tags: macos, applications, mojave, performance, force-quit

I am trying to open Discord.app but it doesn't open, instead I get a box that says

> The application "Discord.app" is not open anymore.

I press cmd shift esc and I can see Discord.app in the list, but selecting "force quit" does nothing.

Activity Monitor does not contain an entry for Discord.app, when I search "Discord" there are actually no results.

Running `ps -ax | grep Discord` at the terminal returns no results. `sudo pkill Discord` error statuses and outputs nothing, `sudo killall Discord` errors `No matching processes were found`.

How can I open discord again?

Comment: Try re-installing it. It's quick on macOS.

Comment: @user14492 I can't delete or replace the old Discord.app because it's in use

Comment: Try either: restart the pc or open Terminal then ‘killall Discord’. If neither work ‘sudo rm -rf /Applications/Discord.app’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it by restarting the computer. Annoying bug.